# Mask unmask in textfield

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have a `textfield` which I wanted to mask completely dynamically where user can not see the value. But label I wasnt as it is.

eg : this is my text field

```js
{
  xtype: 'textfield',
  label: 'search',
  disabled: true,
  disabledCls: 'someCls',
  itemId: 'searchText'
}
```

In this function I wanted to mask it

```
function : someRendomMethod(){
    var view = view.getView();
    var textfieldData = view.down('#searchText');
    var user = view.loginData;
    if(user == "InCorrect"){
        textfieldData.inputCell.mask()
    }else{
        textfieldData.inputCell.unmask()
    }
}
```

Here I want my textfield should be there but inputcell should be hidden/masked.

Thanks for help

Comment: Is this what you want? https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ko1

Answer (score 0):

> where user can not see the value. But label i wasnt as it is

So for this you can make custom masking dom element and append inside of input dom. You can use the method to create the dom element [`Ext.DomHelper.createDom()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/modern/Ext.dom.Helper.html#method-createDom).

You can check with working [**Fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2ko2)

**CODE SNIPPET**

> JS code

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Demo',
            padding: 10,
            fullscreen: true,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                itemId: 'txtMask',
                labelAlign: 'top',
                label: 'Name',
                value: 'Test'
            }, {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                items: ['->', {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    ui: 'action',
                    text: 'Mask',
                    handler: function (btn) {
                        var text = btn.up('panel').down('textfield'),
                            inputCell = text.el.down('.x-input-wrap-el');

                        if (btn.getText() == 'Mask') {
                            /**
                             * Create custom mask dom element
                             */
                            let maskDom = Ext.DomHelper.createDom('<div class="input-cell-masking"></div>');
                            /**
                             * append into input dom
                             */
                            inputCell.appendChild(maskDom);
                            btn.setText('Unmask');
                            /**
                             * Set the input only read mode true
                             */
                            inputCell.down('input').dom.readOnly = true;
                        } else {
                            btn.setText('Mask');
                            /**
                             * remome custom mask dom element
                             */
                            inputCell.down('.input-cell-masking').destroy();
                            /**
                             * Set the input only read mode false
                             */
                            inputCell.down('input').dom.readOnly = false;
                        }

                    }
                }]
            }]
        })
    }
});
```

> CSS code

```
<style>
    .input-cell-masking {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        z-index: 11;
        position: absolute;
    }

</style>
```